# Set up a local/remote test server to automatically run automated Robotium tests in Android studio using a Task Schedular

Tags: java, android, automation, automated-tests, robotium

The problem I am experiencing is having to execute the test cases within  Android studio using the Run -> Run "Tests" method or adb shell am instrument method. I would like theses tests to be run automatically using a Task Scheduler without any input from me.

After some research I found that to make this possible is to build a Test server, and use a Task Scheduler and start a log file that will help to document the test results of what is being tested in the android app.

The Automation tests should also automatically pull the project's latest source code(Programming language used is Java).

How can I achieve all of this within Android Studio?